# CSS stylesheet not loading on linked page

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I have a site that has multiple pages.  The first page is just a listview with icons and links to the other pages.  CSS stylesheets work fine on the first page, but when I go to one of the linked pages, my custom css stylesheet (and js for that matter), related to that page, is being ignored.  If I look in the FF inspector I see that it has dropped the associated lines that tell it about my stylesheet.  If I directly go to the desired page or if I hit refresh, the styles look fine, but whenever I come from a link off the first page, the styles are gone.  I see no errors when loading the page.  Is this a know issue?  How can I force it to not ignore my stylesheets.

I am using jquery mobile 1.4.5 in addition to my own.

Looking further.  It looks like hitting the link is appending the body of the 2nd page at the end of the first and not simply loading the 2nd page.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that by default links behave a little different than normal when using jQuery Mobile.  The don't do a full page load, but instead only inject the part contained in a div marked with data-role="page".  I did not know this.

http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.1.1/docs/pages/page-links.html